# add primary and foreign keys to table mariadb

Tags: python, mysql, mariadb, primary-key, ddl

how can i do to add primary key on table that is a random uniq, generated key

```
CREATE TABLE t (id INTEGER UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY)
```

**python code**

```
import random
def uniqueid():
   seed = random.getrandbits(8)
   while True:
     yield seed
     seed += 1
```

unique_sequence = uniqueid()

How can I do please to call this function in my mariadb query?
Thank you in advance,

Answer (score 1):

What you are describing is close to something that can be implemented natively in MySQL/MariaDB using [`UUID()s`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_uuid):

> A `UUID` is designed as a number that is globally unique in space and time. Two calls to `UUID()` are expected to generate two different values, even if these calls are performed on two separate devices not connected to each other.

Table creation:

```
create table mytable (id varchar(64) primary key);
```

Insertion:

```
insert into mytable values(uuid());
```

Selection:

```
select id from mytable;
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddlde](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.4&fiddle=b3d55c1ee883c56f33bcaf1dd9af3a6f)**

Comment: thank you I followed your steps and got this error **
NameError: name 'uuid_to_bin' is not defined**

Comment: @salsa: sorry, that's a MySQL function that is not supported in MariaDB. Answer updated.

Comment: cursor.execute("INSERT INTO table2 (id1, code, Name ) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)",
               uuid(), v0, v1 )

Comment: I think it should be: `cursor.execute("INSERT INTO table2 (id1, code, Name ) VALUES (uuid(), %s, %s)", v0, v1 )`

Comment: oh it works Danke, and for the foreign key I did  cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE table1 (id2 binary(8) primary key, code VARCHAR(10), name VARCHAR(10), id1 binary(8), FOREIGN KEY(id1) REFERENCES table2(id1));").

Comment: do you know how will be the insert request?

Comment: ja of course I will do it. please if you have ideas about how to add foreign key in query tell me.

Comment: @salsa: I think that I answered the question that you have asked. Comments are not really meant to ask new questions. For that, you may want to *ask a new question*, providing context, sample data and desired resuts.